# ScheduledExecutorService - update data inside

Tags: java, android

I have ScheduledExecutorService and I'm trying to update data inside without result

```
public void myMethod(final String myString) {
    myExecutor.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println(myString);
        }
    }, 0, 10000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
}
```

now I want to change this string from other place in app by

```
myMethod(myString);
```

Mow I have more than 1 thread and sometimes have old and sometimes new data ?
How to fix it ?

Answer (score 1):

One possibility would be to shutdown your `ExecutorService`. This will stop your submitted task.

```
myExecutor.shutdown();
myExecutor.shutdownNow();
```

If you want to schedule it again, you need to create a new `ExecutorService` tough, since once its shutdown it cannot be reused. Then you can reschedule your task with a new value for `myString`.

```
private void scheduleTask(ExecutorService service, String myString) {
    service.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println(myString);
        }
    }, 0, 10000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```
public class Test {
    private static final ScheduledExecutorService EXECUTOR = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1); // single instance                
    private static final Lock LOCK = new ReentrantLock(); // for locking
    private static final AtomicBoolean RUNNING = new AtomicBoolean(false);

    private static String globalString;

    public void myMethod(String myString) throws InterruptedException {
        LOCK.lockInterruptibly();

        try {
            globalString = myString;

            if(!RUNNING.get()) {// this will make sure only one runnable runs
                EXECUTOR.scheduleAtFixedRate(() -> {
                    System.out.println(globalString);
                }, 0, 10000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

                RUNNING.set(true);
            }
        } finally {
            LOCK.unlock();
        }
    }
}
```

At first there will be no `Runnable` running, so when `myMethod` will be called first time, `RUNNING.get()` will return `false`, thus the `EXECUTOR` will schedule a `Runnable`. Also it will flip the value of `RUNNING` to `true`. Afterwards for all invocation no new `Runnable` will be created, but the `myMethod` will update the `globalString` which is printed by the `run` method.

The `LOCK` is to make sure only one thread can execute the logic of `Runnable` creation and other things at a time.

Make sure to `shutdown` the executor after the job is done.